# NSAttributedString created from HTML code with the use of NSHTMLTextDocumentType converts blank lines to spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, foundation

Basically, I am converting HTML code received via a websites JSON API from raw HTML to an attributed string. This effort to remove some of the HTML specific codes, whilst also keeping some degree of formatting, such as underlines/bold text/etc. There is an issue I'm experiencing however, HTML code converted to the attributed string seems to ignore any blank lines.

> So for example:
>
> 1. Step one.
> 2. Step two.
> 3. Step three.
>
> Becomes:
>
> 1. Step one. 2. Step two. 3. Step three.

For whatever reason it appears as if it is either substituting the newlines for a space. I can't seem to work this out but it's making this function basically unusable. I'd much rather use an included API to handle the conversion as the several available categories available don't seem to handle all of the HTML, leaving things like  in the cells, which is not something I can use. Furthermore, I prefer to use one of the included APIs because it is highly unlikely to break in future versions. Is there anything that can be done to overcome this, or is this a bug? For what it's worth, I am using a device on iOS 7.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[post.comment dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSRange rangeOfTitle = NSMakeRange(0,[attrStr length]);
[attrStr addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0f] range:rangeOfTitle];
```

Comment: Could you show the html code equivalent of your example?

Comment: @Larme sure can. It's a 4chan comment. Here is a link to a copy of the HTML obtained from the JSON API: http://pastebin.com/6k903qp7

Comment: I tried your code and didn't get issue: http://imgur.com/4FwmUHU

Comment: @Larme how odd. This is what I am seeing: http://imgur.com/E2gBYfY
May I ask what settings your UILabel has set, or could you perhaps post a code snippet, it seems very strange.

Comment: Nothing particular: numberOfLines:0, and I don't see what else could be cause the issue.

Comment: @Larme I seem to have worked it out. The 4chan API, for whatever reason mixes <br/> tags with actual newlines (/n). By running a replacement of \n with <br/> it seems to process correctly. As for what I sent you, that seems to also be a strange exception, I copied that from the console.

Answer (score 0):

[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\</br>"];

Then do your conversion. This should work.

Note: you can also check for "\r" --> newline

Comment: You undid the code formatting of the code, which results in the second string argument looking wrong (because `</br>` is HTML and is sent directly to the browser, which interprets it rather than displaying it).

Comment: The issue I actually encountered was that I had actually implemented my own HTML stripping class and there was a remnant of it affecting the received HTML. So basically what was happening is that <br> tags were being replaced with /n newlines, as @KenThomases said, <br> will interpret a line break and display it whilst /n is rather meaningless when not enclosed some tags that make it relevant. It was basically like adding whitespace to code, it wont change what the compiled result does but the source code appears somewhat different.

Comment: @Terry174, my comment is actually just in regards to the appearance of nferocious76's answer here on Stack Overflow. His answer contains a string literal `@"</br>"` but that's not apparent because his code is not formatted as code. I edited it to be code-formatted but he edited it back and I don't understand why, because it makes his answer look wrong.

Comment: This is working, I'm using it. only that stackoverflow hid my @"</br>" it should be  withString:@"</br>"];.. 

:/

Comment: @KenThomases Ah, I see now. I was wondering why, I couldn't quite make sense of his answer, though I understand now. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: that back slash do the trick it is visible now, but it should only be @"</br>"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had long since forgotten about this question since it was posted until I received a notification that someone had proposed an answer. The cause of this issue and why it wasn't able to be recreated by others was simple due to the fact that the HTML was actually being parsed and line breaks were being turned into \n new lines. This was more of an artefact from a HTML stripping class which I was writing but then decided to handle it differently. Unfortunately due to awkward place where I had this method placed it was not immediately obvious.

Comment: @Terry147 we are facing same issue getting top much gaps inbetween text..we have tried ur solution bt not able to sort this issue can u pls share help us for same.